# Css - Align image to bottom with vertical-align not working

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I've settle up sizes, table-cell, and stuff, yet it is not working. I need to align the girl image on the bottom of the div, the text and button are fine.

Here is my code:

```
    <style type='text/css'>
.wrapperbannerbanner{
   overflow:hidden;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:15px;
   font-weight:bold;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color:#FF9900;
}
.toppadding {
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-right: 2px;
}
.left2222{
   position: relative;
   /* float: left; */
   left: 12px;
      text-align:left;
}
.generalbanner001 {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-top: 0.5%;
/* margin-bottom: 8px; */
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 80px;
height: 35px;
position: relative;
float:left;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-khtml-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
text-shadow: none;
}
.generalbanner001:hover {
  background: #0a0d0f;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.conferir001 {
padding:8px 0 0 10px;
}
.imageleft1222{
   float: left;
   left: 4px;
   min-width: 90px;
   height:120px;
   display:table;
}
.imgalign {
width:90px;
height:95px;
vertical-align:bottom;
display:table-cell;
}

</style>
<div class="wrapperbannerbanner">

<div class="toppadding">

<div class="imageleft1222"><div class="imgalign" style="background:url(http://0-media-cdn.foolz.us/ffuuka/board/foolz/thumb/1390/58/13905801439073s.png) no-repeat;"></div></div>

<div class="left2222">
        <span>Vai criar um site? Hospede com quem entende do assunto</span>
        <div class="generalbanner001"><div class="conferir001" style="color:#FF9900;">Conferir</div></div>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

The Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4SmV7/1/

Answer (score 0):

The crux here is setting the `background-position` on `.imgalign`

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/4SmV7/3/)

Change your CSS for `.imgalign` to:

```
.imgalign {
    width:90px;
    height:95px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    display:table-cell;
    background-image:url(http://0-media-cdn.foolz.us/ffuuka/board/foolz/thumb/1390/58/13905801439073s.png);
    background-position:bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

And take the inline styles out for `.imgalign`:

```
<div class="wrapperbannerbanner">
    <div class="toppadding">
        <div class="imageleft1222">
            <div class="imgalign"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left2222"> <span>Vai criar um site? Hospede com quem entende do assunto</span>

            <div class="generalbanner001">
                <div class="conferir001" style="color:#FF9900;">Conferir</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[More on `background-position` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

> The background-position CSS property sets the initial position,
>   relative to the background position layer defined by background-origin
>   for each defined background image.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but there is a space below the image, there is no margin or padding below it, so do you know why is this happening?

Comment: Just realized what's going on, it's the height. So background-position: bottom is only aligning the image to the bottom of the div, that's good, but I also need to align the image div itself to the bottom of the other div. I forgot to mention, but the height must be a fluid.

Answer (score 0):

You try to align bottom a div with a `background-image`. You need to set the `height` of this div equal to his parent height, and set the `background-image` alignment to bottom center

Answer (score 0):

So you're using a background image that you need to align to the bottom, correct?

In that case, I would get rid of the class "imgalign" altogether, and have the below CSS on its container:

```
.imageleft1222{
    float: left;
    left: 4px;
    min-width: 90px;
    height:120px;
    display:table;
    background-image:url(http://0-media-cdn.foolz.us/ffuuka/board/foolz/thumb/1390/58/13905801439073s.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

It's better to list the background properties separately because the Firefox browser doesn't always display it properly if you group them all into 'background'.